# Add values in one column based on value of another SQL

Tags: sql

I have a data set here:

```
YOA    Count
2014    43
2014    2
2014    17
2016    47
2015    191
2017    185
2016    26
2014    119
2016    33
```

What I'd like to do is write a SQL query that displays:

```
2017 - all counts for 2017
2016 - all counts for 2017
2015 - all counts for 2017
2014 - all counts for 2017
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why do you want to display "all counts for 2017" for all years?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT YOA, SUM(count) total
FROM tableName
GROUP BY YOA
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT YOA,SUM([Count]) FROM myTable GROUP BY YOA
```